# C# queue - do I need concurrency

Tags: c#

In case 2 different threads are enqueuing and dequeuing to and from a queue. Why do I need to use concurrency `Queue`. One is pulling out of the structure and one pushing I.

Why is thread safety important here?
Due to the internal structure?

Comment: One example: What if the queue is empty and both the enqueue and dequeue requests overlap?  Hilarity might ensue.

Comment: No, you really don't need any synchronization as long as you don't care about results. Synchronization (locks or specialized classes) is only needed if you need correct and predictable behavior. Could you please clarify if your concern is correctness or just staility of .Net run-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can <s>It's necessary to</s> use `ConcurrentQueue`. For example, suppose the two threads are pushing and popping the same item. The reading thread sees that there's an item in queue, but the writing thread hasn't finished writing it yet: now the reading thread has read junk.

Edit: [Alexei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov) is right, you can implement your own instead of using `ConcurrentQueue`. But I'd recommend against it as the library implementation is likely better than what you can create.

Comment: Clearly it is not "necessary to use `ConcurrentQueue` " - OP can use locks or write they own version that behaves correctly...

Comment: Right, but why would you want to do that? Unless OP is trying to create a highly performant system, correctness and readability trumps miniscule performance gains. The question is more about why thread safety is necessary. (naively locking isn't the fastest either)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you `ConcurrentQueue<T>`
The concurrent queue designed to accept multiple threads reading and writing to the queue without you need to explicitly lock the data structure